# SharePoint JSON formatting empty date field with no color

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, date-time, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am using a conditional format for the cells but I want that the empty cells keeps the default color, but with my conditional format the cells with no information are in red color.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField <= @now, 'black',if(@currentField <= @now + 7776000000 && @currentField > @now,'black','black'))",
    "font-weight": "=if(@currentField <= @now, 'bold',if(@currentField <= @now + 7776000000 && @currentField > @now,'semi-bold','normal'))",
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField <= @now, 'red',if(@currentField <= @now + 7776000000 && @currentField > @now,'orange','green'))",
    "padding-left": "14px"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON Formatting, you can check if Date & Time column is blank like:

```
Number(@currentField) == 0
```

You can find other ways to check if date & time column is empty or not at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)

**GitHub sample** for reference: [Formatting a column when a date column is blank](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/blob/master/column-samples/date-check-blank-format)

---

For your scenario, try using this JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, '', if(@currentField <= @now, 'black',if(@currentField <= @now + 7776000000 && @currentField > @now,'black','black')))",
        "font-weight": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, '', if(@currentField <= @now, 'bold',if(@currentField <= @now + 7776000000 && @currentField > @now,'semi-bold','normal')))",
        "background-color": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, '', if(@currentField <= @now, 'red',if(@currentField <= @now + 7776000000 && @currentField > @now,'orange','green')))",
        "padding-left": "14px"
    }
}
```

Comment: it´s work , thanks!!!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!